# SpringBootJpa in clause with subMatching

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

How to apply like with in clause in spring boot jpa.Below is the class.

```
@Table(name="media")
public class Media {

 @NotBlank
 private String url;

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 Long id;

 @ElementCollection
 private Set<String> tagList = new HashSet<String>();

 public Media(String urlString) {
      this.url = urlString ;
 }
}
```

For example if there is a row with tagList ["mentos", "hurre"] and i want to search for "men" or ["men","hu"] this row should come ?
I have defined below method but it return a row only if string completely match.

```
Set<Media> findByTagListIn(List<String> tagList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query by specification like below:

```
//MediaRepository
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;
...
List<Media> findAll(Specification<Media> spec);
```

and create that specification in service class.

```
//MediaService
List<Media> findMediaByTags(List<String> tags){

Specification<Media> specification = (Specification<Media>) (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
  Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
  for (String tag : tags) {
    predicate = criteriaBuilder.and(predicate,
        criteriaBuilder.isMember(tag, root.get("tags")));
  }
  return predicate;
};
return mediaRepository.findAll(specification);
}
```